# nestjs pg test connection maps prod db from ConfigService windows

Tags: typescript, postgresql, testing, connection, nestjs

I experience some weird behavior regarding setting up a test postgres connection on linux contra windows. When I develop on windows I run my tests with

```
"test:e2e:win32": "set NODE_ENV=test && jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
```

logging the `process.env` inside of the constructor body of `app.module.ts` *AND* the tests it successfully gives back `test` as expected. But the database which is created based on the `ConfigService` configuration

```
export default () => ({
  pg: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: '...',
    password: '...',
    database:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? 'db_development'
        : process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging'
        ? 'db_staging'
        : process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? 'db_test'
        : 'db_production'
  },
});
```

creates the database as `db_production`.

`app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration]
    }),
    ConfigModule.forFeature(configuration),
    SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        host: configService.get<string>('pg.host'),
        port: configService.get<number>('pg.port'),
        dialect: 'postgres',
        username: configService.get<string>('pg.username'),
        password: configService.get<string>('pg.password'),
        database: configService.get<string>('pg.database'),
        models: [Store, Reservation, Clothing, User]
      })
    }),
  ],
})
export class RootModule {
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection()
    readonly connection
  ) {
//on linux it successfully yields db_test connection on windows it gives db_production
    console.log('connection', connection); 
//yields "test" BOTH on linux and windows
    console.log('env', process.env.NODE_ENV);
  }
}
```

When running it on linux it works as expected running with

`"test:e2e:darwin:linux": "NODE_ENV=test && jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"`

Not that I think the command is relevant, since the `logs` yields "test" in both environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It considers the space in the test command.
It fixes it by changing

```
"test:e2e:win32": "set NODE_ENV=test && jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
```

to

```
"test:e2e:win32": "set NODE_ENV=test&& jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
```